# How can I use .split to eliminate a specific character if this are repeated in one word?

Tags: javascript

I have a basic question, but fundamental for me. At the time I use ".split" in a word with same characters, it's split in all the same characters.
Example:
'isidro'.split('i')
(3) ["", "s", "dro"]

So, how can I choose keep a single 'i'; and not eliminate both of them?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a pattern of which one to keep?

Comment: why not `const x=i;` then `isidro.split(x)` ?

Comment: Can you update your question to display the exact return you would like to see? Is it `["i", "sid", "ro"]` or is it ["is","idro"]? With either of those `split` will now give you want you want by default becasue that is not how `split` works

Comment: What is the output you want to get?

Comment: Well, to explain better, using de **.split** operator I want to get the next output: ["is", "dro"]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const unique = (value, index, self) => {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
};

console.log("isidro".split("").filter(unique));

console.log("------------")

console.log(Array.from("isidro").filter(unique));
```

And by unique character

```js
console.log(
  "issdidro".split("").filter((value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index || value !== "i";
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for [Array.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

In your case`split()` is working like this:

The division of the string that is split is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.

In your case you are providing the pattern `'i'` so the string will be divided into three parts. Each slice point is omitted so the `i` substrings you are expecting are the slice points, hence they are not returned. Visualize this where the piped i's are the slice points that will not be returned and the rest will be the substrings that will be returned:

<sub>|i|`s`|i|`dro`</sub>

Finally you get an empty string in the first position of the returned array because of this rule in the documentation:

- If separator appears at the beginning (or end) of the string, it
  still has the effect of splitting.  The result is an empty (i.e. zero
  length) string, which appears at the first (or last) position of the
  returned array.